# Unable to make acronyms in latex

Tags: latex, acronym, glossaries

Hi I am trying to get acronyms in my document but I am continuously failing in doing that.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]
\include{ch1}
end{document}
```

and my acronym code is in the chapter file

```
\chapter{ch1}
\acrfull{WLAN} is used as a trial for my example and problem

\newacronym{wlan}{WLAN}{Wireless Local Area Network}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I am also defining this in small letters. What does second bracket means then?

Comment: The second bracket is how the acronym appears in the text.

Comment: Please stop editing your question to include additional questions! One post should only include one question and invalidating an existing answer is even worse!

Answer (score 0):

You're defining the acronym `wlan`, but you are using the acronym `WLAN`. Decide on which of the two you want and the be consistent:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]
\chapter{ch1}
\acrfull{WLAN} is used as a trial for my example and problem

\newacronym{WLAN}{WLAN}{Wireless Local Area Network}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the reply. I am also defining this in small letters. What does second bracket means then?

Comment: is there any way to define the acronyms in separate file and then call them in some way

Comment: If  you have a new question, use the "Ask Question" button at the top right

Comment: yes sure but I can post 1 question in one hour and If the answer to my question is not big maybe you could answer here or ill edit my question.